# How to get todos in relation with a todolist?(solved)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

The app should behave like this:
Once the login is done I have all my todolists, so I have to get all the todos for that todolists, not only the todos from a specific todolist.

The only thing I want to happen is that the todos should appear only on the relative todolist.

AXIOS REQUEST

```
getTodos(todolist) {
      axios
        .get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todolists/${todolist}/todos`)
        .then((res) => {
          this.todos = res.data;
          console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },
```

Vue template

```
    <div
      v-if="todolists.length > 0 && !loading"
      class="todolist-row h-100 py-5"
      :class="todolists.length == 1 ? 'todolist-1' : ''"
    >
      <div class="todolist" v-for="todolist in todolists" :key="todolist.id">
        <div class="td-title">
          <h5 class="text-center m-0 py-2 text-light">
            {{ todolist.title }}
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="td-inputs d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <input class="px-2" type="text" />
          <button type="submit">
            <i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="px-2">
          <div v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id">
            {{ todo.title }}
          </div>

          <div><i class="fas fa-times" @click="cancel(todolist.id)"></i></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

ROUTE

```
Route::get('todolists/{todolist}/todos', 'TodoController@index');
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function index(Todolist $todolist) {
        return $todolist->todos;
    }
```

I've tried this computed property (passing it then in the v-for) but it didn't work

```
computed: {
    filtered() {
      this.todolists.forEach( todolist => {
        this.todos.filter( todo => todo.todolist_id == todolist.id)
        return this.todos
      })
    }
  },
```

-----------------------------MISTERY SOLVED--------------------------------

in the TodolistController I've just add "->with('todos')" and it returns me a todos array of objects inside the todolist array of objects.

So then with a v-for on "todolist.todos" I get just the todos I need.

I didn't even need an api for this.

TodolistController

```
$userTodolist = Todolist::where('user_id', Auth::id())->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->with('todos')->get();
```

VUE template

```
<div v-for="todo in todolist.todos" :key="todo.id">
     {{ todo.title }}
</div>
```

Comment: Can you update your question with your routes file please?

Comment: do `dd($todo->todolist)` and check why it is returning `null` instead of the model. maybe related to your data in your DB. Also, post code not images. makes it har to copy/paste.

Comment: Updated. However the DB seems ok, all the relations I need are where they need to be.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a route parameter for this route. Your method signature `Todo $todo` is going to cause Dependency Injection to happen, not Route Model Binding; so `$todo` is an injected new non existing Todo model instance.

If you want that to be Route Model Binding you would need to have a route parameter named `todo`. I would setup the route differently and make it more of a nested resource idea:

```
Route::get('todolists/{list}/todos', ...);

public function index(Todolist $list)
{
    return $list->todos;
}
```

Assuming the relationship on Todolist is named `todos` to get all its todo items.

Comment: Sure, why didn't I think about that? Obviously I need a parameter in the route referring the todolist, thanks!!!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. I change the route, then in Vue i call the function in the created, but I can't pass in the todolist.id